# Convert new hard disk for mirror-ing on existing system

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, raid-1

I am trying to make raid1 mirroring on new hard disk, disk1.

I deleted partition to make unallocated space, right click on C: -> mirror -> disk1 then I get message "All disks holding extents for a given volume must have the same sector size, and the sector size must be valid" like you can see on image below.

There is 2 disks, disk0 (main one which I want to mirror from) and disk1 (where I want to mirror)

I tried to make same partitions on disk1 like there are on disk0, but without success.

Here is image with error and both disks partitions [image]

What I am trying to make here is RAID1 on disk1 on windows 10 pro 64 bit, I followed this steps but this doesn't work for me [How to mirror the system and boot partition (RAID1)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/mirror-system-boot-partition-raid1), also this one [Establish and boot to GPT mirrors in 64-bit Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/establish-boot-to-gpt-mirrors)

How I can make same partitions like on disk0 and setup raid1 on disk1 ?